# Transformation of pdf to calculate cdf

Tags: statistics, random

A random variable $X$ has a pdf given by

$$\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{2(x+2)}{25}, -2 < x <3$$

Let $Y=X^2$ be a transformation of $X$.

$1$. Is this transformation one-to-one? Find the support of $Y$.

$2$. Derive the cdf of $Y$.

Comment: The transformation is not one-to-one; $(-1)^2=1$ and $1^2=1$ yet $-1\neq1$.

Comment: fixed, sorry needed to add spaces